# awk: take entries from file and add values in between

Tags: awk

I have the following file:

```
2    some    
5    some     
8    some    
10   thing
15   thing
19   thing
```

Now I want to end up with entries, where for "some" 2,5,8 correspond to rows where there is a 1, everything else is 0. It doesn't matter how many rows there are. This means for "some":

```
0
1
0
0
1
0
0
1
0
0
```

and for "thing"

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
1
0
```

Is this possible in a quick way with awk? I mean with something like:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=10;i++) entries[$i]=0 for(f=0;<=NF;f++) entries[$f]=1' testfile.txt
```

Comment: So you want to create a file named "some" that has rows that are either "0" or "1", and lines 2,5, and 8 are the "1"s?

Comment: thats about right..although it doesn't has be to named "some"..but the second column should match the 1s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another `awk`, output terminates with the last index

```
awk -v key='thing' '$2==key{while(++c<$1) print 0; print 1}' file
```

to add some extra 0's after the last 1; add `END{while(i++<3) print 0}`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this seems to work in order to produce "some" data:

```
$ cat file1
2    some
5    some
8    some
10   thing
15   thing
19   thing

$ awk 'max<$1 && $2=="some"{max=$1;b[$1]=1}END{for (i=1;i<=max;i++) print (i in b?1:0)}' file1
0
1
0
0
1
0
0
1
```

Similarly , this one works for "thing" data

```
$ awk 'max<$1 && $2=="thing"{max=$1;b[$1]=1}END{for (i=1;i<=max;i++) print (i in b?1:0)}' file1
```

Alternativelly, as mentioned by glennjackman  in comments we could use an external variable to select between some or thing:

```
$ awk -v word="some" 'max<$1 && $2==word{max=$1;b[$1]=1}END{for (i=1;i<=max;i++) print (i in b?1:0)}' file1
# for thing just apply awk -v word="thing"
```

You can achieve better parameterizing using an awk variable like this:

```
$ w="some" #selectable / set by shell , by script , etc
$ awk -v word="$w" 'max<$1 && $2==word{max=$1;b[$1]=1}END{for (i=1;i<=max;i++) print (i in b?1:0)}' file1
```

Comment: You should pass the word to awk with `awk -v word="thing"` and compare with `$2==word` -- that will make it easier to parameterize on the shell side

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, that could be done. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: In the end that looks so easy. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

perl:

```
perl -lanE '
        push @{$idx{$F[1]}}, $F[0] - 1;  # subtract 1 because we are working with 
                                          # (zero-based) array indices
        $max = $F[0];     # I assume the input is sorted by column 1
    } END {
        $, = "\n";
        for $word (keys %idx) {
            # create a $max-sized array filled with zeroes
            @a = (0) x $max;
            # then, populate the entries which should be 1
            @a[ @{$idx{$word}} ] = (1) x @{$idx{$word}};

            say $word, @a;
        }
' file |  pr -2T -s | nl -v0
```

```
 0  thing   some
 1  0       0
 2  0       1
 3  0       0
 4  0       0
 5  0       1
 6  0       0
 7  0       0
 8  0       1
 9  0       0
10  1       0
11  0       0
12  0       0
13  0       0
14  0       0
15  1       0
16  0       0
17  0       0
18  0       0
19  1       0
```

Comment: Haven't done much with perl, but this looks nice. Thanks